# jPlayer does not play mp3 plus the volume controls and start/end times do not show

Tags: jquery, json, jplayer

This is racking my brain.  There are zero errors in the console.log for Chrome, the playlist is populating the jPlayer, nicely, but the songs won't play, the volume controls don't show and the times (start and end) don't appear.

Here's my code which works dandy and I'm using the latest JQuery library and latest ver of jPlayer.

```
//Define the playlist
var playlist = [];

//Set the prequisites
var cssSelector = {
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
};
//Options
var options = {
    swfPath: "libs/jwPlayer/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3",
    solution: 'html, flash',
    preload: 'metadata',
    volume: 0.8,
    muted: false,
    wmode: "window",
    playlistOptions:
            {
                autoPlay: false
            }
};

//jPlayer
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);

//Get the JSON file to dynamically load the playlist
$.getJSON("mp3/playlist.json",
        function(data) {  // get the JSON array
            $.each(data['data'].tracks,
                    function(index, value) {
                        myPlaylist.add({
                            title: value.title,
                            composer: value.composer,
                            performedby: value.performedby,
                            mp3: value.mp3

                        });
                    });
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HERE'S my jPlayer as it looks in the browser:

[image]

UPDATE: Justin, below, asked about the relative path of the playlist.json file.  Here's a screencap from Netbeans 8.0 showing where that file resides:

Justin, hope this helps:

[image: This is the location of the playlist.json file.]

Also, here's the JSON file itself:

```
{
        "data": {
            "tracks": [
                {
                    "performedby": "Some group - 2005",
                    "url": "http://www.somedomain.com",
                    "solovocal": "Phil",
                    "soloinstrumental": "",
                    "lyricsby": "Peter",
                    "musicby": "Phil",
                    "composer": "Phil",
                    "arrangedby": "Phil",
                    "copyrightby": "Peter and Phil",
                    "copyrightdate": "2005",
                    "recordeddate": "2005 at a music studio",
                    "title": "Sheperd of the Fold",
                    "mp3": "02ShepherdoftheFold.mp3",
                    "notes": "Original lyrics written by Peter. Music by Phil"
                }, {
                    "performedby": "US Navy Band Guam - 1982 - 1984",
                    "url": "",
                    "solovocal": "",
                    "soloinstrumental": "Peter - Flugelhorn",
                    "lyricsby": "",
                    "musicby": "Chuck Mangione",
                    "composer": "Chuck Mangione",
                    "arrangedby": "Peter for the US Navy Band",
                    "copyrightby": "Chuck Mangione",
                    "copyrightdate": "1968",
                    "recordeddate": "1977 Eastman School of Music, Rochester, NY",
                    "title": "The XIth Commandment",
                    "mp3": "11thCommandment830508.mp3",
                    "notes": "Chuck Mangione composed The XIth Commandment for Stephen Gadd, who gave the world premiere performance during his percussion graduate recital on February 16, 1968 at the Eastman School of Music."
                }

            ]
        }
    }
```

Thanks everyone...

UPDATE:

I got the playlist to load nicely using promises. Also, the first song plays perfectly.  That being said, however, the NEXT and PREV buttons don't work neither does clicking on the next song advance the player. Here's my JS code:

```
    //Define the playlist
    var playlist = [];

    //Options
    var options = {
        swfPath: "libs/jwPlayer/Jplayer.swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        solution: 'html, flash',
        preload: 'metadata',
        volume: 0.8,
        muted: false,
        wmode: "window",
        errorAlerts: true,
        warningAlerts: true,
        playlistOptions: {
            autoPlay: false,
            loopOnPrevious: false,
            shuffleOnLoop: true,
            enableRemoveControls: false,
            displayTime: 'slow',
            addTime: 'fast',
            removeTime: 'fast',
            shuffleTime: 'slow'
        }
    };

    //Set the prequisites
    var cssSelector = {
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        currentTime: '.jp-current-time',
        duration: '.jp-duration',
        fullScreen: '.jp-full-screen',
        gui: '.jp-gui',
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        mute: '.jp-mute',
        next: '.jp-next',
        noSolution: '.jp-no-solution',
        pause: '.jp-pause',
        play: '.jp-play',
        playbackRateBar: '.jp-playback-rate-bar',
        playbackRateBarValue: '.jp-playback-rate-bar-value',
        playBar: '.jp-play-bar',
        previous: '.jp-previous',
        repeat: '.jp-repeat',
        repeatOff: '.jp-repeat-off',
        restoreScreen: '.jp-restore-screen',
        seekBar: '.jp-seek-bar',
        shuffle: '.jp-shuffle',
        shuffleOff: '.jp-shuffle-off',
        stop: '.jp-stop',
        title: '.jp-title',
        unmute: '.jp-unmute',
        videoPlay: '.jp-video-play',
        volumeBar: '.jp-volume-bar',
        volumeBarValue: '.jp-volume-bar-value',
        volumeMax: '.jp-volume-max'
    };
    //Define the main Playlist
    var myPlaylist;
    //Set the JPLAYER OBJECT
    var jpObj;

    //Window onLoad function
    $(window).load(function() {

        //STEP 1
        //BEGIN LOADING PAGE IMPORTS
        //Load the navigation console
        $("#nav-container").load("imports/nav.html");
        //Load the main content for this page
        $("#main-container").load("imports/home.html");
        //Load the nav content for this page
        $("#topbar").load("imports/topBar.html");
        //Load the header content
        $("header").css({'background-image'
                    : 'url(images/'
                    + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]
                    + ')'
        });
        //Load the Footer
        $("footer").load("imports/footer.html");
        //Load the Copyright stuff
        $("#copyright").load("imports/copyright.html");
        //END LOADING PAGE IMPORTS!

        //jPlayerPlaylist initialization
        myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);

        var mediaPlayer = jQuery('#jquery_jplayer_1');

        //Get the JSON file to dynamically load the playlist
        $.getJSON("playlist.json", //This is located in the ROOT folder
                function(data) {  // get the JSON array
                    $.each(data['data'].tracks,
                            function(index, value) {
                                myPlaylist.add({
                                    tracknbr: index,
                                    title: value.title,
                                    composer: value.composer,
                                    performedby: value.performedby,
                                    mp3: value.mp3
                                });
                                //copy the original Playlist into the playlist array
                                playlist[index] = myPlaylist.original[index];
                                // Attach a done, fail, and progress handler for the asyncEvent
                                if (playlist.length > 0) {
                                    $.when(asyncEvent())
                                            .then(
                                                    function(status) {
                                                        //Progressing nicely
                                                        console.log(status + ", things are going well!");
                                                        jpObj.jplyr(status + " - Progressing Nicely");
                                                    },
                                                    function(status) {
                                                        //ERROR Catching
                                                        console.log(status + ", you fail this time!");
                                                        throw new Error("There was an error loading the playlist.");
                                                    },
                                                    function(status) {
                                                        //Working...wait for it...
                                                        if (status === "") {
                                                            //Not ready
                                                            return;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                            );
                                }
                            });
                });


        //Set the jpObj for Promises to load the playlist
        jpObj = {
            jplyr: function(stat) {
                try {
                    if (stat === "Success! - Progressing Nicely") {
                        console.log("My Status:: " + stat);
                        //jPlayer initialization
                        mediaPlayer.jPlayer({
                            options: options,
                            cssSelector: cssSelector,
                            ready: function() {

                                for (var i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++) {
                                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                                        title: playlist[i].title,
                                        mp3: playlist[i].mp3
                                    }).jPlayer("play");
                                }

                            }//END OF READY FUNCTION
                        });
                        // The next/previous commands
                        $(this).click(function() {
                            //$("#jquery_jplayer_1").trigger($.jPlayer.event.ended);
                            $(".jp-next").jPlayer("next");
                        });
                        $(this).click(function() {
                            //$("#jquery_jplayer_1").trigger($.jPlayer.event.play);
                            $(".jp-previous").jPlayer("play");
                        });
                        //Initialize the inspector
                        $("#jplayer_inspector_1")
                                .jPlayerInspector({
                                    jPlayer: $("#jquery_jplayer_1")
                                });
                    } else {

                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {

                    var errMsg = "There was an error processing the Jplyr Object:" + e;
                    console.log(errMsg);
                    throw new error(errMsg);
                    return false;
                }

            }

        };
        //Promise function...
        function asyncEvent() {
            //Set the JQ.Defered
            var myJplyr = $.Deferred();

            // Set object as a promise
            myJplyr.promise(jpObj);

            // Resolve the deferred
            myJplyr.resolve("Success!");

            // Reject the deferred
            myJplyr.reject("Failure!");

            // Use the object as a Promise
            jpObj.done(function() {
                jpObj.jplyr("We\'re Good..."); // Fire the function on the comeback
            });
            // Return the Promise so caller can't change the Deferred
            return myJplyr.promise();
        }
    });
```

Comment: In the mp3/playlist.json file, are the MP3 references relative to that file or something else? Might just be the paths aren't matching up for the media.

Comment: The mp3/playlist.json file is located in the same directory as the actual mp3 files.  Everything else is working; the array for myPlaylist is being populated, the value.xxxx is coming back just fine... I just don't understand how to get the MP3 file to play and the times/volume controls to show up.